# Changing variable value in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

We can defince variables in xaml like:

```
<system:Double x:Key="ListHeight">320</system:Double>
```

Is there any way we can change its value using setters? Like

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count, ElementName=FileListBox}" Value="0" >
   <Setter TargetName="ListHeight" Value="400"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Basically I need to use this valiable for mentioning height of different elements. SO if I need to change height, I'll cahnge this variable and all elements will have increased height. And value of this variable depends on hiw may items are there in the list. If there are none or less than 5 items we'll have a specific height of the list. If the items are more than 5, we'll have another value for it.

Comment: Like this? No. `TargetName` is for xaml elements only.

Comment: @TomerAgmon1 any other way to bind it with something like `{Binding Items.Count, ElementName=FileListBox}`?

Comment: Why not bind to some sort of `ViewModel`? These types of variables are constant. I'm not sure what the specific need is, but there has to be another way to solve it.

Comment: @TomerAgmon1 I have edited the question with more details.

Comment: This can be solved using a `Converter`